# ¿Cómo obtener una filas de dos fila en una consulta a MySQL?

Tags: mysql

tengo una base de datos MySql con la siguiente forma:

```
entrada/salida      | id
--------------------------------
01/01/2015 10:00:00 | 10101010-2
01/01/2015 18:00:00 | 10101010-2
01/01/2015 09:30:00 | 12121212-4
01/01/2015 15:00:00 | 12121212-4
```

Y estoy usando estos datos para realizar unos gráficos pero necesito que la respuesta sea de esta manera

```
entrada             |  salida             | id
------------------------------------------------------
01/01/2015 10:00:00 | 01/01/2015 18:00:00 | 10101010-2
01/01/2015 09:30:00 | 01/01/2015 15:00:00 | 12121212-4
```

Es decir, necesito que me junte dos filas en una sola, siempre y cuando sean de la misma fecha (xx/xx/xxxx) sin importar la hora y de que tengan el mismo id.

¿Es posible hacer esto?

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto [tour] y de paso conseguir su primera medalla, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando [how-to-ask] para tener mas posibilidades de recibir una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando MIN y MAX podrias hacerlo

```
SELECT MIN(entradaSalida) as entrada, MAX(entradaSalida) as salida, id FROM TABLA GROUP BY id, DATE_FORMAT(entradaSalida, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

No lo probé y no tengo muy de memoria sql, pero algo así seria la consulta

```
SELECT EntradaSalida FROM TABLE WHERE Id=$id GROUP BY YEAR(EntradaSalida),MONTH(EntradaSalida),DAY(EntradaSalida) LIMIT 2 ORDER BY Id Desc;
```

La primera seria entrada y la segunda salida.
Revisa también GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(EntradaSalida, '%Y%m%d')

Comment: No estas agrupando por id, y solo devuelves 1 valor cuando necesita 3 por registro.

Comment: Asumo que es un ingreso y egreso de empleados o usuarios. Esos empleados o usuarios deben tener un identificador. id_usuario, dni, nick. O algo. Where ese identificador.

Comment: Aun asumiendo eso esta mal, no necesita 2 tuplas por id sino 1 solo. Tu codigo no vale para eso.